# Select data when specific columns have null value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where there are 2 date fields I want to filter and see rows when any one of the date field is null.

```
ID          Date1       Date2
58844880    04/11/16    NaN
59745846    04/12/16    04/14/16
59743311    04/13/16    NaN
59745848    04/14/16    04/11/16
59598413    NaN         NaN
59745921    04/14/16    04/14/16
59561199    04/15/16    04/15/16
NaN         04/16/16    04/16/16
59561198    NaN         04/17/16
```

It should look like below

```
ID          Date1       Date2
58844880    04/11/16    NaN
59743311    04/13/16    NaN
59598413    NaN         NaN
59561198    NaN         04/17/16
```

Tried the code
`df = (df['Date1'].isnull() | df['Date1'].isnull())`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['Date1'].isnull() | df['Date2'].isnull()
print (df[mask])
           ID     Date1     Date2
0  58844880.0  04/11/16       NaN
2  59743311.0  04/13/16       NaN
4  59598413.0       NaN       NaN
8  59561198.0       NaN  04/17/16
```

**Timings**:

```
#[900000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [12]: %timeit (df[df['Date1'].isnull() | df['Date2'].isnull()])
10 loops, best of 3: 89.3 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit (df[df.filter(like='Date').isnull().any(1)])
10 loops, best of 3: 146 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you the solution worked and also for sharing the timeit for both the solutions for comparison

Comment: This is great solution for the inverse, find columns with data, leveraging `df.notnull()`

Answer (score 5):

Quickly see if either column has any null values

```
df.isnull().any()
```

Count rows that have any null values

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

#### Get rows with null values

(1) Create truth table of null values
(i.e. create dataframe with True/False in each column/cell, according to whether it has null value)

```
truth_table = df.isnull()
```

(2) Create truth table that shows conclusively which rows have any null values

```
conclusive_truth_table = truth_table.any(axis='columns')
```

(3) isolate/show rows that have any null values

```
df[conclusive_truth_table]
```

(1)-(3) put it all together

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis='columns')]
```

## Alternatively

Isolate rows that have null values in any specified column

```
df.loc[:,['Date1','Date2']].isnull().any(axis='columns')
```

Isolate rows that have null values in BOTH specified columns

```
df[ df.loc[ :,['Date1','Date2'] ].isnull().sum(axis=1) == 2]
```

Comment: Re this df.loc[:,['Date1','Date2']].isnull().any(axis='columns'), it is not supported anymore KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
In [7]: df[df.filter(like='Date').isnull().any(1)]
Out[7]:
           ID     Date1     Date2
0  58844880.0  04/11/16       NaN
2  59743311.0  04/13/16       NaN
4  59598413.0       NaN       NaN
8  59561198.0       NaN  04/17/16
```